# What does sparsely compute mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra

I heard someone say a neural network needs to sparsely compute the output.

I get what compute means, I get what a sparse matrix is, but what does sparsely compute mean?

Comment: Could you cite the reference so that we can see the context?

Comment: I heard it with my ears, so unfortunately I can't privde more context than that